# Convert an object to an array suitable for an ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, object

I have the following object and I need to convert it into an array for an ajax post. Does anyone know how to do this in javascript/jquery?

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object]
    0: Object
      name: "authenticity_token"
      value: "d8792991d3941352c00474e3f6b4081bd1d7e818"
    1: Object
      name: "_method"
      value: "POST"
    2: Object
      name: "email"
      value: "sdaasdsa"
    3: Object
      name: "password"
      value: "asddadsadasdsa"
```

Here is my jquery post, i need the object to be the fields array:

```
     jQuery.post(formAction, fields).done(function(response) {
         console.log(response);
     }, "json");
```

Thanks
Pete

Comment: looks like you have an array of objects here

Comment: jQuery.makeArray(Obj)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Description: Convert an array-like object into a true JavaScript array.

```
 var myArray =  $.makeArray(myObj);
```

Or

```
 var myArray  = myObj.toArray();
```

You can also do it like

```
var myArray ={};
$.each(myObj, function(name, value){
  //console.log(name, value);
 myArray [myObj[key].name] = myObj[key].value;
});
```

Comment: Can u tell which of the above is better in terms of performance ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to iterate the object in a similar way:

```
    tosend = {};
    for(key in object) {
      tosend[object[key].name] = object[key].value;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var url;
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                fields
            }),
        }).done(function (msg) {
            alert("success");
        });
```